# Apply class after element is loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a document where a content of a table is loaded within container with AJAX.

I need to apply styling to the table, and although my JS is within

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

it appears I am still unable to apply the CSS to the table. Is there a way to add some listener to do it after the table is loaded?

---

UPDATE:

Fixed it with running function after delay

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.myElement').addClass('myClass');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: How is this table getting loaded? Is it loading dynamically? in any case.. you can just add a class to the table and the style will apply automatically.

Comment: Your styles aren't applying to content loaded with AJAX?

Comment: Yes, it is a weirdest thing. I have several tables on the page and I am able to style all but one... Almost thinking of adding a delay on styling to that particular one.

Comment: Did you apply the styles with javascript and not in a stylesheet, if so it only works on elements that are present at the time you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to apply the css class once the table is loaded with the data using ajax ? If yes, you can do that in the callback function of your ajax call.

```
$(function(){

  $("#tblAwesome").load("gettablecontent.aspx",function(){
        $("#tblAwesome").addClass("newClass");
  });

});
```

Comment: I was looking at the .load() function, but I am not sure where the content is loading from.

Comment: you can load it from an external page(ex: gettablecontent.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can't 'access' to your element in document's ready event if it's loaded after, with an asynchronous query.

Why waiting for the elements to be loaded to apply style ? Because you know your elements will be created in a specific table (with a specific id ?) the very best solution must be applying the style in your 'static' css code, targetting your table's elements.

This way the elements are styled as they are added to the dom.

Comment: This element is used elsewhere and I only need to restyle it on this particular page, without affecting other instances... Is there a way to listen when it is finished loading?

Comment: and you can's define a specific class on elements you want to restyle while you add it to the DOM ?

Comment: I suppose I could add a class that means nothing to ther instances and only appears proper in this case... Not a prefered solution though.